# Prove that radical of an ideal is contained in the Jacobson of the ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Can someone give any hint on how to start? I have a feeling that I have to prove that all maximal ideals containing $I$ will contain the radical of $I$.

Answer (score 3):

The radical of $I$ equals the intersection of the prime ideals containing $I$. Every maximal ideal is prime so the radical is contained in every maximal ideal containing $I$.